# How can I bind a link(href) to any of the dropdown options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown-menu that I auto populate base on my Ajax call.

Before Ajax

[image]

After Ajax

[image]

---

They look like in the DOM

## HTML

```
<select class="rn-dropdown" id="rn-dd" href="http://localhost:8080/BIM/teacher/reports/section-exercise/assignment?assessmentId=206a9246-ce83-412b-b8ad-6b3e28be44e3&amp;classroomId=722bfadb-9774-4d59-9a47-89ac9a7a8f9a">
    <option value="class-view">class view</option>
    <option value="s-00586">Student S00586</option>
    <option value="s-00587">Student S00587</option>
    <option value="s-00588">Student S00588</option>
    <option value="s-00589">Student S00589</option>
    <option value="s-00590">Student S00590</option>
</select>

_
```

---

My goal is to re-direct each student to some href(www.site.com).
I'm not how to get that done.

This is what I've

## jQuery

```
// Auto Populate the dropdown-menu
$("#rn-dd.rn-dropdown").append('<option value="' + userId + '"> <a href="">' + name + '</a></option>');

// Dropdown-menu change
$('#rn-dd').on('change', function() {
    $(this).find("a").attr('href', "www.google.com");
});
```

---

Any helps / hints will mean a lot to me.

Comment: `href` is only valid in `<a>` elements, not `<select>`.

Comment: Why are you assigning `i` but not using it?

Comment: I will use somewhere else, but not now. Sorry, I should take it out.

Comment: You never set the variable `href` before you do `href.replace('student', 'assignment')`. If it's supposed to be the `href` attribute, there's no `student` in there, so there's nothing to replace.

Comment: You're right. I took it off. now.

Comment: @Barmar : For some reasons, my `<a>` doesn't appear in the DOM. Do you know why ?

Comment: I don't see `<a>` in the HTML you posted.

Comment: Because I couldn't get it to populate. Clearly, I did that as part of my jQuery.

Comment: You can't put `<a>` inside `<option>`.

Comment: I was trying to do as `@cbender` suggested.

Comment: Can you please answer this ? It seem like you got this more than anyone else.

Comment: The answers that are already posted seem correct, and I upvoted one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom `data-*` attribute to set the base `href` for your `change` event - then use `location.href` to actually do the change:

```
<select class="rn-dropdown" id="rn-dd" data-href="http://localhost:8080/BIM/teacher/reports/section-exercise/assignment?assessmentId=206a9246-ce83-412b-b8ad-6b3e28be44e3&amp;classroomId=722bfadb-9774-4d59-9a47-89ac9a7a8f9a">
```

And the JS:

```
$('#rn-dd').on('change', function() {
    var selectedValue = this.value;
    var baseHref = $(this).data("href");

    //Do some logic on the href to get what you want
    //Not sure what that is based on the question
    var href = baseHref; //magic

    //Redirect
    location.href = href;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the href attribute in your SELECT element, in fact its not a standard attribute for SELECT.  Use .val() to get the value of the selected SELECT option than append it to the given url.  Use history.location to redirect to the given url.

```
 $('#rn-dd').change(function() {
     var i = $(this).val();
     var href = "http://localhost/?student=" + i;
     window.location = href;
 });
```